# WPF problem with DataContext in TabControl with List as source

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, datacontext

I'm having problem binding DataContext to my TabControl in WPF application, but mayby let's start from begining. Basically I want to generate tabs for each object in a list by using generic UserControl and ViewModel

In my `MainWindow.xaml` which itself is binded to a corresponding `MainViewModel.cs` I have my source of problem, that is although `TabControl.ItemTemplate` is binding correctly and I'm seeing correct tab name, the `TabControl.ContentTemplate` is not, and my question is why and what another approach should I use?:

```
<TabControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding ClientViewModels.IndexOf(SelectedClientViewModel)}" >
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:ClientGenericUserControl 
                DataContext="{Binding DataContext.ClientViewModels[SelectedIndex]}" />
            
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

in `MainViewModel.cs` class:

```
public ObservableCollection<Client>? Clients { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<ClientGenericViewModel>? ClientViewModels { get; set; }
```

as for `Client.cs` class:

```
public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

as for `ClientGenericViewModel.cs` clss:

```
public class ClientGenericViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Client? Client { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Product>? Products { get; set; }

    private Product? _selectedProduct;

    public Product? SelectedProduct
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedProduct;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._selectedProduct != value)
            {
                this._selectedProduct = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `ClientGenericUserControl.xaml` for now I just want to display name:

```
<TextBlock 
    Text="{Binding Client.Name}" />
```

as I said, I'm having trouble binding DataContext in ContentTemplate. When I'm changing something in this GenericUserControl, all changes are visible so it's binding to it's corresponding ViewModel properly, but these changes are visible for all items in list.
What am I missing?

Comment: The `DataContext` in your `ContentTemplate` is not `MainViewModel`.  It is... whatever the data type of `SelectedClient` is.   And do not then try to *set* `ClientGenericUserControl`'s `DataContext` in your `ContentTemplate`.   It already will have that `DataContext` by virtue of being in the template.   Just *use* it.  Finally, you might want to bind to *either* `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` but not both.